# CABasicAnimation disappear when home button is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, cabasicanimation

I'm implementing a game, in which i have some CABasicAnimations.
For example, like this :

```
CABasicAnimation * borddroit = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
borddroit.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
borddroit.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:749.0f];
borddroit.duration = t;
borddroit.repeatCount = 1;
[ImageSuivante2.layer addAnimation:borddroit forKey:@"borddroit"];
```

I put it in pause with this function :

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}
```

When my application is entering background, because the user push the home button, the animations correctly set in pause, but when i re-open my app, the animations have disappeard.

How could i fix it please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is correct and built-in behavior. When you leave the app, all animations are removed from their layers: the system calls `removeAllAnimations` on every layer.

This doesn't matter, usually, for the following reason: suppose you animate a ball from point A to point B and it is halfway to point B in the animation when the user switches away from your app. When the user comes back, the animation is gone, but the ball is *at* point B, so the app can just continue. All that happens is that we've skipped some of the animation part.

Comment: Ooooh :/ So their is no solution to keep them onto the screen when resumed ? Because the image that i want to move is border sets. So when the user is gone, if all the image is going done, it makes a bad behaviour / game experience

Comment: When resumed, if you want that animation to appear again, you'll have to create it again.

Comment: (And you didn't need to pause it when suspending the app, since it will be removed anyway.)

Comment: Hello, how do i recreate the animations? viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear are not recalled when reentering in foreground mode.

Comment: But consider `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

Observe `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and re-animate `CAAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in either your `UIViewController` or in your `UIView` class. No need to resume or start again animation. It will handle by its own :)

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(becomeActive:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];


-(void)becomeActive : (NSNotification*)notification
  {
    NSLog(@"app become active");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All animations are removed when view disappears from the visible area (not only when app goes into background). To fix it I created custom `CALayer` subclass and overrided 2 methods so the system doesn't remove animations - `removeAnimation` and `removeAllAnimations`:

```
class CustomCALayer: CALayer {

    override func removeAnimation(forKey key: String) {

        // prevent iOS to clear animation when view is not visible
    }

    override func removeAllAnimations() {

        // prevent iOS to clear animation when view is not visible
    }

    func forceRemoveAnimation(forKey key: String) {

        super.removeAnimation(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

In the view where you want this layer to be used as main layer override `layerClass` property:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {

    return CustomCALayer.self
}
```