# Stop the call of -removeAllAnimaitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, interrupt

Currently on the iOS platform, when the home button is pressed, `-removeAllAnimations` is sent to each view's `layer` property.

## I *desperately* need to stop this behavior!

I am currently using a `CABasicAnimation` that animates the drawing of a circle to act as a timer.

Here is a gif of the process. The timer starts and the animation begins smoothly (pardon the poor fps). Once the home button is pressed and I come back to the app, the animation immediately finishes.

[image]

I am using the `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag` method to detect when the timer is stopped. This is all working out really well, until I press the home button.

Pressing the home button immediately completes the animation and prematurely completes the timer.

Is there **any** way to stop this behavior such as a method on `UIViewController` or some property I can set in the `.plist` of my project?

Here is the source for my first statement. [CABasicAnimation disappear when home button is pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852554/cabasicanimation-disappear-when-home-button-is-pushed)

Here are my current attempts to solve the problem.

1. Subclass `CALayer` to override `-removeAllAnimations` in hope of preventing the stopping of the animation.
2. Performed method swizzling in the `+load` method in an extension on the `CALayer` class that swizzles `-removeAllAnimations` to some bogus method. I have determined that the bogus method is being called, yet the same behavior is still being experienced.

Comment: You can't prevent it from being called.  You may be able to override the method in the layers, however.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Great point. I will look into subclassing `CALayer` and overriding `removeAllAnimations`.

Comment: take a look a Facebook's POPAnimation library - https://github.com/facebook/pop, for more control in situations such as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I want to thank @KudoCC for the response.

While the given solution might work, I have found an easier way with the `-[CAAnimation removedOnCompletion]` property.

```
CAAnimation * anim = ...;
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
// anim will now continue after home button press
```

This solution seems to override the default calls of `-[CALayer removeAllAnimations]` issued by the OS when the home button is pressed.

Comment: Correct and simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I create an example to animate the position of a CALayer using `CABasicAnimation`.

The idea is to store some context of the animation when app goes to background and restore the animation when app goes back.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL animationStoped ;
    CFTimeInterval time ;
    CGPoint position ;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *viewAnimate ;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _viewAnimate = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)] ;
    _viewAnimate.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;
    [self.view addSubview:_viewAnimate] ;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [self animation] ;
    [_viewAnimate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation.position"] ;
    _viewAnimate.layer.position = CGPointMake(250.0, 350.0) ;
    time = [_viewAnimate.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleEnterBackgroundNotification:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil] ;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleDidBecomeActiveNotification:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil] ;

}

- (CABasicAnimation *)animation
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"] ;
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0)] ;
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 350.0)] ;
    animation.duration = 5.0 ;
    animation.delegate = self ;
    return animation ;
}

- (void)handleEnterBackgroundNotification:(id)nty
{
    CAAnimation *aa = [_viewAnimate.layer animationForKey:@"animation.position"] ;
    animationStoped = aa != nil ;
    if (animationStoped) {
        CALayer *presentationLayer = _viewAnimate.layer.presentationLayer ;
        position = presentationLayer.position ;
        CFTimeInterval now = [_viewAnimate.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
        time = now - time ;
    }
}

- (void)handleDidBecomeActiveNotification:(id)nty
{
    if (animationStoped) {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [self animation] ;
        animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position] ;
        animation.duration -= time ;
        [_viewAnimate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation.position"] ;
    }
}
```